# How do I set initial state in React with Apollo graphql and graphene-django

Tags: reactjs, apollo, graphene-django

I'm currently learning how to use apollo client as for a graphql API exposed via graphene-django's `DjangoObjectType` node. Here's an example

I define a node

```
class CompanyNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        filter_fields = {
            'domain': ['exact'],
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith']
        }
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    companies = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CompanyNode)
```

A typical query looks like this

```
query queryCompanies {
  companies {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response is

```
{
  "data": {
    "companies": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Q29tcGFueU5vZGU6MQ==",
            "name": "great",
            "__typename": "CompanyNode"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Q29tcGFueU5vZGU6MTI=",
            "name": "awesome",
            "__typename": "CompanyNode"
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using apollo client with react for the frontend and my queries are returning okay. A typical component looks like this.

To initialize some state in `index.js` I'm writing the companies data to the cache.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

cache.writeData({
  data: {
    companies: {
    edges: [],
    typename: 'CompanyNodeConnection',
    __typename: 'CompanyNodeConnection',
  },
  },
});
```

Then in my component, I'm reading from my cache like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const Companies = () => {
  const root = useApolloClient().cache.data.data;

  const QUERY_ALL_COMPANIES = gql`
  query getCompanies {
    companies {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `;

  const { loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_COMPANIES);

  if (error) {
    return <p>{JSON.stringify(error?.graphQLErrors[0]?.message)}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Companies</h2>

      {loading ? (
        <p>loading</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {root['$ROOT_QUERY.companies'].edges.map((com) => {
            const { id: edgeKey } = com;
            const {
              node: { id: itemNodeId },
            } = root[edgeKey];
            const { id, name } = root[itemNodeId];

            return (
              <div key={id}>
                  {name}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Companies;
```

Now my question is, is this the proper way to initialise this state? Secondly, is this the proper way of reading this particular query from the cache?

I'd like to see other patterns and opinions on what works. I'm thinking this pattern of reading state is too brittle.

Comment: you should use `data` from `useQuery` ... `  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_COMPANIES);` .... NOT apollo internals (`root`, it can be changed).

Comment: Okay @xadm. So when using that is it possible to set some default state and how? If I were using redux I could just do `initState = { companies: [] }`. But with apollo client I have no idea how to do that.